# track logs for scheduler using Whenever gem, Ruby and sinatra

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra, whenever

I have written scheduler using "Whenever Gem", where I have 2 schedulers in my scheduler.rb file. 
I want to get the logs from the scheduled tasks, so I have `set :output, "log/cron_log.log"` in scheduler.rb. currently all the logs for all the schedulers are logged in my log file, Instead I want the output to be logged for only one scheduler and not for any other scheduler. 
 How can I do this?

My scheduler.rb

```
    set :output, "log/cron_log.log"

   #donot set output log for this.
    every 6.hours do
      rake "sidekiq:restart"
    end

   #set output log only for this scheduler 
    every :day, :at => '01:00am' do
      rake 'prune_users:older_than_2months'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
# donot set output log for this.
every 6.hours do
  rake "sidekiq:restart"
end

# set output log only for this scheduler 
every :day, :at => '01:00am' do
  rake 'prune_users:older_than_2months', :output => {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}
end
```

Btw, you can refer at link: https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs